# In the Netherlands, are reference letters commonly required?

Tags: references, recommendation-letter, netherlands

I want to apply for the R&D position in large high-tech company in Netherlands. I currently work in academia and I have never worked in a private company.

When applying for the job in the Netherlands, is it common practice to require a reference letter?

Comment: It is not uncommon to ask for actual references (email addresses / phone numbers) though, to verify your story. But that is with your permission, so you don't need to worry now. Large high-tech companies have HR departments which are capable of handling a variety of backgrounds, especially since Europe does not have a single culture in this respect.

Comment: @MSalters Thnx!

Answer (score 5):

Normally not.

Whenever I have searched for a high-tech job in the Netherlands I was almost never asked for reference letters.

Normally you are required a CV/resume and a cover letter, sometimes a list of exam with grades, but reference letters is not really requested as common practice.

Comment: Thnx. Is it true that Netherlands HR prefer more strict, less self complimentary attitude in the resume?

Comment: @MaxL, if this answers you, the Dutch are modest people. Another trait owing its roots to Calvin, the Dutch typically downplay wealth, and frown upon those who flaunt their success. But, as all generalization, might not always be true.

Comment: @L.Dutch: "Large hi-tech companies" are mostly in the south of the Netherlands (Eindhoven area), which is not the Calvinist part of the country.

Comment: @MSalters, of course you meant to say the west part of the Netherlands (Rotterdam area), which is the Calvinist part of the country ;)

Comment: @MSalters it says nowhere "the calvinists"

Answer (score 2):

Reference letter? No. References in general? Yes.

I work for a large contractor and am currently working as a developer at a high-tech company in Eindhoven area on the R&D department. This company did not ask for references. The previous project that I worked on was in finances and did require references.